# offline location based android application

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, location, offline

I am trying to make an application that displays some points of interest, along with some brief information when I click them, on a map. I also want to display my location on the map as a point on the map as well. The points refer to some archeological sides so there will be no internet coverage.

I managed to successfully finish the [MapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview)  from google developers side.

Now my problem is this:

1. How can I use the map offline?
2. How I add my location that will be updated automatically?
3. How can I draw a custom line between the point so I navigate people through the sides?

In the future I'd like to add a Location based AR functionality as an other Activity. I'm just adding this information in case of any constrains.